# Django query set giving attribute_error when trying to get a set with multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

First, here are my models. Each string has from 1 up to 3 performers, each performer linked to several strings:

```
class Performer(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="None")
    description = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)

class String(models.Model) :
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    step = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    process = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    performer = models.ForeignKey(Performer, related_name='performer',   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    performer2 = models.ForeignKey(Performer, related_name='performer2', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    performer3 = models.ForeignKey(Performer, related_name='performer3', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
```

I need to make set of all Strings related to single performer. However, if I try to use `string_set` to get all Strings where any of the Performer foreign keys point to that string like so:

```
p = Performer.objects.get(name="smth")# so p is a performer object
s = p.string_set.all()
```

I get this issue:

```
 AttributeError: 'Performer' object has no attribute 'string_set'
```

Also I've tryed to use filters with related name, but this gives me the same error. Is there a way to get a _set based off of one of any foreign key fields that all point to the same type?

Answer (score 3):

By providing `related_name` in each of `performer`, `performer2`, `performer3` relations you override the default `related_name` linking from `Performer` class which would be `string_set`. Now to get the `String` for each of these relations you would have to get them like the following:

```
p = Performer.objects.get(name="smth")# so p is a performer object
p.performer.all() #first one which would actually be a queryset
p.performer1.all() #second one which would actually be a queryset
p.performer2.all() #third one which would actually be a queryset
```

This would be true only if you have single `String` and single `Performer` related to each other but you should keep in mind that query like `p.performer1.all()` can actually return 2 or more `String` objects which would have a relation with this one `Performer`. This would make things even more cumbersome.

Keep in mind that the `ForeignKey` creates one-to-many relation...

The models structure you provide would have issues with doing filtering you want. The better model design would look like the following:

```
class Performer(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="None")
    description = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
    strings = models.ManyToManyField(String, related_name='performers')

class String(models.Model) :
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    step = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    process = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, default=None)
```

This design would allow you to execute:

```
p = Performer.objects.get(name="smth")# so p is a performer object
s = p.strings.all()
```

Comment: But can i execute "s.performers.all()" where s is single string object with these models?

Comment: Yes you can. But keep in mind that its the many-to-many relationship so `s.performers.all()` would return a queryset as well, not a single object

Comment: This ManyToManyField tool is awesome, i fixed everything with it, thanks! *brofist*